# How to perform a function when a sound finish playing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm building a sound quiz application that requires the user to guess the correct sound from multiple sounds option. I was wondering if there is any function that preform an action when the sound is finished playing like AVAudioPlayer .isplaying or .stop.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for I think

```
struct Manager
{    
    //Required Objects - AVFoundation
    ///AVAudio Session
    static var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!

    ///AVAudio Recorder
    static var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?

    ///AVAudio Player
    static var player: AVAudioPlayer?
}
```

**Play Music**

```
//Set player with audio File
do
{
    try Manager.player = AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: returnPathAtSelectedIndex(fileName: fileName))
    //Set required delegates and Values

    Manager.player?.delegate = self
    Manager.player?.volume = 1.0
    Manager.player?.prepareToPlay()
    Manager.player?.play()
}
catch
{
    print("Error while playing music: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**Audio Player delegates**

```
//MARK:- Audio Player Delegates
extension RecordingManager: AVAudioPlayerDelegate
{
    //MARK: Audio Player Finishes Playing audio
    /**
     Called when a sound has finished playing.
     - parameter player: player instance
     - parameter flag: Bool player is running or not successfully
     */
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "StoppedPlaying"), object: nil)
        player.stop()
        Manager.player?.stop()
        Manager.recordingalreadyPlayedStatus = false
        print("Finish Playing")
    }

    //MARK: Audio Player error occur while Playing
    /**
     Called when an audio player encounters a decoding error during playback.
     - parameter player: player instance
     - parameter error: Error if occurs
     */
    func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,error: Error?)
    {
        print("Encoding Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying ?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying

Answer (score 0):

Create your `AVAudioPlayer`

set yourself as the delegate of the player.

Implement the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` delegate method. It will get called when the sound finishes playing

Consult the docs on `AVAudioPlayer`, the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol, and the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` delegate method for more information.

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:) and the avaudiodelegate code so i can get an idea how to do it

Comment: I don't have any code that I can screenshot for you. I'd have to write some, just like you would. I told you the steps you need to follow. Read the docs, then follow the steps. If you get stuck or can't get it working, edit your question with your code and we'll help you debug it, but you need to write some original code yourself, without getting spoon-fed sample code on the internet. If you don't take that step you'll never progress as a developer.